# Member is inaccessible when overloaded operator is friended

Tags: c++

The code doesn't link when I try to compile, the error is "undefined reference to operator*" and I think this may be the problem.

This is my .h file:

```
namespace space{    
          class Number{
            .
            .
            public:
                 friend Number operator*(double scaler, const Number& one);
            private:
            int val;
            std::string unit;
            .
       }
```

This is the .cpp file:

```
using namespace space;
Number operator*(double scaler, const Number& one){
    Number temp((one.val * scaler), one.unit);
    return temp;
  
}
```

But I'm getting the error (it's right on the `one.val`):

```
member "space::Number::val" (declared at line 47 of ".../Number.hpp") is inaccessibleC/C++(265)
```

Comment: `using namespace space;` -> `namespace space { `?

Comment: the operator you make friends with is one in namespace `space`, while the one you defined seems to be not in that namespace

Comment: all of the class is in the namespace, i cant move the operator outside of class, right?

Comment: @Jarod42 the namespace ends after the class definition if that's what you mean...

Comment: `using namespace` does not place functions in that namespace. Compiler may deduce that class member should be in the namespace (because it knows that class is in the namespace), but free functions do not get such behaviour. Jarod's suggestion will solve your problem.

Comment: such a stupid mistake. thanks a lot, didn't noticed it!

Comment: its easy too forget that many names are just shortcuts. When you declare `foo` inside namespace `bar` you actually declare `bar::foo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The friend declaration is a declaration of a function:

```
namespace space{    
class Number{
    friend Number operator*(double scaler, const Number& one);
    // ...
};
```

As this is inside a namespace, the function that is declared is `space::operator*`. Then you define `::operator*` in the global namespace. Those are two different functions. You made one operator a friend of the class, but define a different one.

The operator that you made a friend must be defined inside the namespace (or you declare the one in global scope as friend):

```
namespace space {
Number operator*(double scaler, const Number& one){
    Number temp((one.val * scaler), one.unit);
    return temp;
}
}
```